# How to remove Facebook "Currently Ineligible for Submission"?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, fbsdk

The app being developed is developed on iOS and Android. The iOS version created the Facebook app id first, and only asking for email, fb user id, and full name, therefore doesn't need for review.

Then the Android version came along, using the same facebook app, but it incorrectly and unnecessarily asking different (higher) permission for the app, including About Me information and other stuff. That makes the Facebook gives warning that the app need to be submitted for review on the permission page. Now there's a warning on the facebook app dashboard that the app is ineligible for submission because it missing some data it needs.

Currently Ineligible for Submission
Your submission is missing data in the following fields:
- Privacy Policy URL

Now the Android version has already refined so it asks the same permission as the iOS version, but the warning won't go away. How can I make it go away without providing privacy policy URL? (provided that it was working without issue before the Android integration came along)

Comment: you can place a placeholder privacy url ?

Comment: @Shubhank I want it to be reverted to the previous condition, without the need of providing privacy url. If I add privacy url, then I'm going the route of submitting the app to facebook for review. Ultimately, I mean I don't want the app needs to be reviewed, because it was in a state that doesn't to be reviewed before.

Comment: maybe drop a mail to facebook support ?

Comment: what permission you are asking by code to Facebook login. and are you make a readpermission or write.?

Comment: @Shubhank that will be my last resort. I'm thinking that it's just a problem of configuration to pull the app out of reviewing mode.

Comment: @NitinGohel the iOS version asks for name, user id, and email only (public profile). the Android version was incorrectly also asks for about me, which is not in the list of public profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After meddling around, I finally found the way. Just go to App Review menu in the Dashboard, on the Current Submission section, click on "Start Over".